# How can I insert custom metadata records using jsforce in nodejs?

Tags: api, jsforce

I am trying to create a custom metadata record using jsforce but I cannot find any way to do it in documentation.

I tried Metadata#create(type, metadata)

```
conn.metadata.create('test_custom_metadata__mdt', metadata, function(err, results) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
});
```

But I've got an error saying

```
{ soapenv:Client: Unable to determine type mapping for type {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}test_custom_metadata__mdt.  Type is illegal here.
```

Just to be sure I also tried SObject#create(record) but that obiously didn't work.

Is it even possible to insert custom metadata records through jsforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
conn.metadata.create('CustomMetadata', metadata, function(err, results) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
});
```

> CustomMetadata is the metadata type that is required here.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I just had to tinker with the metadata parameter structure

Comment: Could you share what parameter structure you ended up using? I'm unable to find any examples of creating/updating custom metadata records.